# List all the packages required in a script assuming package::function() in R

Tags: r, list, package

Let´s assume that all the non-base R functions in a script are called by `package::function()`. Therefore, it don´t have any full package load during the script run. Let´s assume that we have the a R script called `run.R` with the following contents.

```
"data.table::fread(file)"
```

In this example, the script would need the `data.table` package. I am looking for a R function that reading this external `run.R` script would give the code to install all the requested packages i.e.:

```
install.packages("data.table")
```

Any idea about existent functions or strategies?

Comment: It is important to highlight that my real script is on disk and require packages that I do not have listed. So, in this case I want to search for all the packages that I will need automatically. Reading manually is exactly what I am trying to avoid

Comment: But how I am going to discover which packages are inside the script?

Comment: sorry, may be I misread your question

Comment: Though *very* verbose, R's CHECK (also done with `devtools::check`) functionality complains about functions that are not declared literally or included in packages listed within `DESCRIPTION`.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this using regex:

```
f <- file("/path/to/here/file.R") # set up connection to file

file_lines <- readLines(con = f) # read file into list

close(f)

pckgs <- lapply(file_lines, function(l) { 
  if(grepl("::", l)){
    gsub(".*?([[:alnum:]\\.]+)::.*","\\1", l) 
  } else {
    return(NULL)
  }

})  
unique(unlist(pckgs))
```

I worked under the assumption that package names only contains letters and numbers. you may need to change the regex pattern if that isn't the case.

Update: changed the assumption to include a `.` as per the `data.table` example

Answer (score 2):

The other solutions using regular expressions will also match `::` if it occurs in a comment or string literal.  It's better to parse the script and look for things that parse to the `pkg::fn` operation.  For example:

```r
src <- "data.table::fread(file)"
# Use src <- readLines("source.R") in the real case, or parse the file directly

parsed <- parse(text = src)
parseData <- getParseData(parsed)
parseData$text[parseData$token == "SYMBOL_PACKAGE"]
#> [1] "data.table"
```

**Edited to add:**  You can put this in a function to install necessary packages before running a script.  For example, if these lines are in `~/temp/run.R`:

```r
file <- "not::a::package"
data.table::fread(file)
foobar::notafunction()
```

then you get these results:

```r
installThenSource <- function(file, ...) {
  parsed <- parse(file)
  parseData <- getParseData(parsed)
  packages <- unique(parseData$text[parseData$token == "SYMBOL_PACKAGE"])
  for (p in packages) {
    if (!requireNamespace(p, quietly = TRUE)) {
      message("Installing ", p)
      install.packages(p)
      if (!requireNamespace(p, quietly = TRUE))
        stop("Install of ", p, " failed.")
    } else
      message("Package ", p, " already installed.")
  }
  source(file, ...)
}

installThenSource("~/temp/run.R")
#> Package data.table already installed.
#> Installing foobar
#> Warning: package 'foobar' is not available (for R version 3.6.1)
#> Error in installThenSource("~/temp/run.R"): Install of foobar failed.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that finds strings like `package::function`.

```
findPackages <- function(file){
  txt <- readLines(file)
  inx <- grep('::', txt)
  txt <- txt[inx]
  m <- regexpr('[[:alnum:]]+::', txt)
  pkg <- regmatches(txt, m)
  unique(sub('::', '', pkg))
}
```

This Ubuntu bash command gets all files `*.R` in the working directory with `::` in them.

```
fls <- system2('grep', args = c('-l', '::', '*.R'), stdout = TRUE)
```

Now apply the function to a file that calls functions like that.

```
findPackages(fls[1])
```

And to all such files found with the bash command.

```
pkgs <- lapply(fls, findPackages)
unique(unlist(pkgs))
```